# Leaflet and GeoJSON coordinates usage

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJSON object “feature” stringified as  :

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id": 1039215298,
        "version": 1,
        "reference": "SRO-BPI-12121212",
        "adresse": "235 RUE DU MAUBON",
        "codePostal": "60750",
        "ville": "CHOISY AU BAC",
        "nbrLogements": 2,
        "nbrLogementsDeployes": 2,
        "tauxLogementsDeployes": 100
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            2.87,
            49.44
        ]
    }
}
```

It should point to France.

I want to display the openstreetmap tiles, add a marker using GeoJSON layer and zoom in using the following leaflet commands:

```
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(map);
map.flyTo(feature.geometry.coordinates, 13);
```

The zoom doesn’t work: leaflet zoom to (49.44, 2.87) in Indian Ocean. I have to use the following code to correctly zoom in France:

```
map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(feature.geometry.coordinates[1],feature.geometry.coordinates[0]), 13)
```

Which is inconsistent.
Can you please explain me why the coordinates are correctly displayed with GeoJSON layer but not correctly used by map.flyTo ? Is there a flyTo method for GeoJSON feature?

Comment: See https://macwright.com/lonlat/

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, they are just using different coordinate axis order by definition. FlyTo requires coordinates to be in lat-lon order https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-flyto

> flyTo(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom?, <Zoom/pan options> options?)

and in GeoJSON coordinates must be in lon-lat order https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946.

> A position is an array of numbers.  There MUST be two or more
> elements. The first two elements are longitude and latitude, or
> easting and northing, precisely in that order and using decimal
> numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's because GeoJSON and leaflet use different conventions for the order of latitude and longitude. You just have to switch the order as you did.

GeoJSON [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-21):

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected
> coordinates, longitude, and latitude for geographic coordinates):

and leaflet `flyTo` [method](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-flyto):

> flyTo( latlng,  zoom?, <Zoom/pan options> options?)

When you create the GeoJSON layer with `L.geoJSON(feature)` the coordinates get converted.
But when you access the values directly via `feature.geometry.coordinates` you get raw values from your feature.

There is a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620696/convert-lat-long-into-geojson-object)